# Load multiple files from folder as a loop

Tags: r

I have multiple files in a folder that I would kike to load into R and manipulate, then save as data.table. Is there a way where I can autmate the input and output by defining the files I want to load?

Files in folder:

```
data1.xlsx
data2.xlsx
data3.xlsx
```

My script:

```
data1.d = read.xls("data1.xlsx", sheet = 5, header = TRUE)
data1.d$Date <- format(as.Date(data1.d$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), "%m/%d/%Y")
data1.d$Time <- "17:00:00"
data1.d$OI <- "1"
write.table(data1.d, file="data1.Ready.txt", col.names = T, quote = F,sep=",",row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the list of files from the directory with `list.files` or `dir`, specify the `pattern` if necessary, loop over the `files` with `imap`, read the excel file with `read_excel` (`readxl` package), create the columns with `mutate`, and write it back to new file with `write.table` after changing the file name by replacing the `.xlsx` (`str_remove`) and concatenating the '.Ready.txt' at the end with `str_c`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '^data\\d+\\.xlsx$')
library(readxl)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap(set_names(files, files), ~ read_excel(.x, sheet = 5) %>%             
             mutate(Date = format(ymd(Date), "%m/%d/%Y"),
             Time = "17:00:00", OI = "1") %>%
            select(1,8,2,3,4,5,6,7) %>%
            set_names(c("Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Vol","OI")) %>%
             write.table(file = str_c(str_remove(.y, "\\.xlsx"), 
        ".Ready.txt"), col.names = TRUE, quote = FASLE, sep=",", 
         row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Hi,What if I have two more lines of manipulation of the input? Please see updated questions.

Comment: Sorry, one final question: If I want to change order and names of column: Order: c(1,8,2,3,4,5,6,7) Names: c("Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Vol","OI")

Comment: awesome, now I get it.

Comment: Does the purr package have a way to order the columns by date? Usually I would do this: data1.d[order(as.Date(data1.d$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")),]

Comment: @user2300940  You can use `%>%arrange(as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y"))`